# Why does a lattice of the complex plane form a torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I think it's quite clear what I mean with lattice - so does anyone have an idea how one can see this fact easily?

Comment: Please can you define lattice and torus precisely ?

Comment: Do you know how to identify/glue together the opposite edges of a square to make a torus? You can do the same with a fundamental region of the lattice, so that equivalent points in different regions map to the same point on the torus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Topology and for $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ in $\mathbb{C}$, independent
$\Omega:=\{n_1\omega_1+n_2\omega_2: n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is the lattice of the complex plane

Comment: You mean "gluing" together all 4 edges?

Comment: No. Glue the top and bottom edges together to make a tube. Now bend the tube and glue its two circular ends together.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H5_h-RB0T8

Answer (score 4):

The quotient $\mathbb C/ \Lambda$ is topologically a torus, so every lattice $\Lambda$ defines a torus.

Comment: Sorry I meant it that way, but how do I see that?

Comment: Have you ever played asteroids, the old computer game in which your spaceship must shoot lumps of rock ? If you drift over one of the four edges of the screen then you reappear in a corresponding position at the opposite edge, with the same velocity and acceleration as before.

Comment: Yes I know but why is it a torus because of that?

Comment: Draw a circle around the inside wall of the torus, encircling the hole in the doughnut. Draw a second circle perpendicular to the first, encircling the "meat" of the doughnut. You have mapped the rectangular screen onto the doughnut. Imagine an ant walking on the doughnut, crossing those lines, and compare it with the spaceship going off screen and instantly reappearing on the opposite side.

Comment: @J.Doe the first step is to take $M = \mathbb Z$. Try to see that $\mathbb C/M$ is a cylinder. Do you see how to do it ?